# longitude and latitude bounds of Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The lon and lat is send corretly, but still the markers are not displayed.

```
   $(function () {
       var map;
       var markers = new Array();
       var mapOptions = {
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.4750370, 7.2843),
           zoom: 7,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       };
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);


       function initialize() {
           // var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
           google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', onClickCallback); //listen to zoom event and call function to reload markers
           google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', onClickCallback); //listen to drag/pan event and call function to reload markers

           google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
               onClickCallback(map);
           });
       }


       function onClickCallback(map) {
           var bounds = map.getBounds();

           $.getJSON('http://skiweather.eu/gmap3/markers/index.php', {
               swLat: bounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
               swLon: bounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
               neLat: bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
               neLon: bounds.getNorthEast().lng()
           }, function (data) {
               $.each(data.markers, function (i, marker) {
                   $('#map').gmap('addMarker', {
                       'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude),
                       'bounds': true
                   }).click(function () {
                       $('#map').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                           'content': marker.content
                       }, this);
                   });
               });
           });
       }

       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're simply creating an empty LatLngBounds object, hence why it's defaulting to 1, -1, 180, -180.  You want to find out the bounds of your map instead:

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
```

You'll need to either pass your map object into your onClickCallback function, or make it a global variable.

---

Update: 
Try this instead.  You still want to actually create the map inside your `initialize` function.  :

```
   $(function () {
       var map;
       var markers = new Array();

       function initialize() {
           var mapOptions = {
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.4750370, 7.2843),
               zoom: 7,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           };
           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

           google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', onClickCallback); //listen to zoom event and call function to reload markers
           google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', onClickCallback); //listen to drag/pan event and call function to reload markers

           google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
               onClickCallback(map);
           });
       }


       function onClickCallback(map) {
           var bounds = map.getBounds();

           $.getJSON('http://skiweather.eu/gmap3/markers/index.php', {
               swLat: bounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
               swLon: bounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
               neLat: bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
               neLon: bounds.getNorthEast().lng()
           }, function (data) {
               $.each(data.markers, function (i, marker) {
                   $('#map').gmap('addMarker', {
                       'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude),
                       'bounds': true
                   }).click(function () {
                       $('#map').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                           'content': marker.content
                       }, this);
                   });
               });
           });
       }

       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: how do i make a global variable?

Comment: Instead of creating `var map;` inside your initialize function, do it immediately above that (i.e. outwith any function)

Comment: Ok, I did that but the markers are not visible. I changed the code above.

Comment: That is a valuable addition, but it is not solving the issue of displyaing the markers.

Comment: Your question has changed now, is the problem with the bounds (i.e. your original question) fixed?  Rather than rewrite your question to address a subsequent error in your code, you should really ask a new question.  Regardless... You're using the gmap plugin, you should add this to the tags.  What does the data returned from your PHP page look like?